# Finding general term for an alternating series when the numbers skip odd numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series

When reducing something like:

$\frac{c_0}{6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2}$

and the next term is:

$\frac{c_0}{8 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2}$

Why can the denominator be expressed as $2^n * n!$

I can test this out and see it's correct but how do I see this more formally?

Comment: You are asking why $8\cdot 6\cdot 4\cdot 2 = 2^4\cdot 4!~~$?  Notice that $8\cdot 6\cdot 4\cdot 2 = (\color{blue}{2}\cdot 4)\cdot (\color{blue}{2}\cdot 3)\cdot(\color{blue}{2}\cdot 2)\cdot(\color{blue}{2}\cdot 1) = \color{blue}{2}^4\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 2^4\cdot 4!$.  Generalizing this should be a trivial matter of induction.

Comment: As an aside, $8\cdot 6\cdot 4\cdot 2$ can be simplified and written as $8!!$ where $!!$ stands for [double-factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) (*not to be confused with $(8!)!$*).

Comment: @JMoravitz if you write a full fleshed out answer, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use the product notation.

$\begin{array}\\
2\cdot 4\cdot 6 \cdot ... \cdot 2n
&=\prod_{k=1}^n (2k)\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n (2)\prod_{k=1}^n (k)\\
&=2^n n!\\\end{array}
$